# Are the early versions of the Java Language Specification and VM specification available online?

Tags: java, jls

Oracle has the latest versions of the java specs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ but I was unable to find the older versions. Are these archived anywhere?

Comment: The link cites both the most recent and penultimate versions; as Java SE 5.0 was a sort of watershed, how far back do you need to go?

Comment: I wanted all of them for comparison. Java SE5 corresponds to the JLS 3rd edition and 2nd edition VM spec. So there were just few earlier versions.

Comment: As @Guillaume pointed out, the archive's do not contain the specs but only the jdk, jre. The jdk documentation only contains the api javadoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are still interested - I just had the same problem and found the old specs using the waybackmachine , for instance, the JLS 1st edition is here:

http://web.archive.org/web/20041208124545/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/index.html

Downloading the PDF versions failed, but I can display the online HTML versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look in the [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html). You should be able to find everything you need there.

Comment: Those only contains JRE and JDK, not the JLS.